# Keras custom function : How to rewrite this function in Tensorflow, so it can be decorate by @tf.function as part of autogarph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

`fanouts` tells the shape of  `neigh_feats`, this function cannot be used by tf.function, because I use python‘s own `for loop`, but I don't know how to change the into a Tensorflow style `loop`.

```py
@tf.function
def transform(all_feats, fanouts):
    feats, neigh_feats = all_feats[0], all_feats[1:]
    dim = feats.shape.as_list()[-1]
    feats = tf.reshape(feats, [-1, 1, dim])
    for dim, neigh in zip(fanouts, neigh_feats):
        feats = tf.tile(feats, [1, dim, 1])
        feats = tf.concat([feats, neigh], axis=2)
    return feats
```

Here is an example below:

```py
for item in t:
    print(item.shape)
l = transform(t, [5, 5])
print("result shape: ", l.shape)

(5, 100)
(5, 5, 100)
(5, 25, 100)
result shape:  (5, 25, 300)
```

This example can be run in eager model, but failed in autograph, as I used in Keras.

Comment: Your example code works both in eager and non-eager for me. What is wrong there and what error do you get?

Comment: Before, I get an error says I cannot loop in Tensor, so I guess it's because this function, but right now I can run this function without any error information.

Answer (score 0):

Before, I get an error says I cannot loop in Tensor, so I guess it's because this function, but right now I can run this function without any error information.